# MySQL docker image not working as Local MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, docker

I have `MySQL 5.7` installed on my Windows 10 pc and I am using the same version in a docker image on the cloud. I'm using official mysql image from docker hub.

```
docker run --name my-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -d mysql:5.7
```

Both populated from a single `sql` file. Data on both local and cloud is exactly the same. Now, my problem is that I have a query that I am running on both local and cloud with different result. I am attaching the images for the output of the query. Correct result on local while docker image on cloud gives something else. I was wondering what could be the reason?

This is the query:

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(BIRTH_DATE, "%Y")) AS birthdate, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM customer
    GROUP BY birthdate
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ORDER BY birthdate;
```

[image: Docker image]

[image: MySQL Workbench]

Comment: "Data on both local and cloud is exactly the same. ".  I don't think so.  In any case, why are you storing DOB as a string?  Store it as a date and just use `YEAR(BIRTH_DATE)`.

Comment: Well obviously something is different, either data, or perhaps MySQL configuration options. Try this query on both environments and see what's different in the data: `SELECT BIRTH_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(BIRTH_DATE, "%Y"),  YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(BIRTH_DATE, "%Y")) FROM customer;` Also check `SELECT @@sql_mode;` in both environments.

Comment: Since your images aren't labeled, I don't know which one is which. But the one with the MySQL command prompt shows **44 warnings**. It is likely that that's the problem.